# How to make a connection string a constant in a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, connection-string

I have a dynamic connection string builder due to the fact that I need to use a different DB for each customer.

When I am testing this I want to mock the dynamic connection string builder to return a specific customer string object. The problem I am running into is C# keeps erroring on the connection string as a constant.

```
 private const string connectionString = 
 @"metadata=res://Data/CustomerModel.csdl|res://Data/CustomerModel.ssdl|
 res://Data/CustomerModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
 provider connection string=/""Data Source=MyDB;Initial Catalog=MyCustomer;
 User ID=SomeUser;Password=SomePassword"
```

The current error is:

```
 An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but    
 was not handled in user code

 Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.
```

I know that it is how C# is storing the connection string, what I don't know is how to fix it.
I don't want to use the Connection String builder service that I have because then my test would rely on more than just this "unit". I would like to fake the connection string builder to return that connection string.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What I mean is, the value `some " string` can be written as C# strings `@"some "" string"` or `"some \" string"` (among others). You've shown us what you think is the C# string you want, but apparently something's wrong about it; what is the *value* you want?

Comment: @TimS. I am not sure I follow you. The connection string that I have posted above is what I want to pass to EF to build me a context object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` and build it out manually.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738533(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That just throws the error sooner in the built connection string: Keyword not supported: 'data source'. I guess I am going to have to manually build the connection string in a method.

Comment: I have removed the portion of the answer that attempts to correct your connection string.  It seems EF connection strings are handled differently if from a configuration file than passing a string.